# Testing Bootstrap on jsfiddle

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I'm trying to test some HTML code including bootstrap in jsfiddle, but when including external css references, get this error:

*For external CSS files use the Resources panel on the left.*

Those external references are hosted somewhere in an outside server, but apparently it's not called correctly.

How should I call external css references or external javascripts ?

[image]

Comment: give link of your filddle.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to call external file on jsfiddle is clicking the left panel `External Resources`

In your case, just type
`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css`
`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js`

[Jsfiddle Template](https://jsfiddle.net/obp9x1yr/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the references in the CSS panel, closing the style tag with , eg.

```
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/x7pfa0gr/) (scroll down in the css panel to see it)