# Bootstrap maxcdn affecting my CSS.kindly help me to resolve

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried this piece of code in [jdFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89pd04ot/180/)

I changed the width of .numberCircle to 35px.

Without the Bootstrap CSS its working fine. However if I use Bootstrap CSS it's not working as shown in the jsFiddle output.

**Without Bootstrap CSS:**

```css
.numberCircle {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  position: relative;
}
.numberCircle .height_fix {
  margin-top: 100%;
}
.numberCircle .content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -16px;
  /* Note, this must be half the font size */
}
```

```html
<div class="numberCircle">
  <div class="height_fix"></div>
  <div class="content">1</div>
</div>
<div class="numberCircle">
  <div class="height_fix"></div>
  <div class="content">100</div>
</div>
<div class="numberCircle">
  <div class="height_fix"></div>
  <div class="content">10</div>
</div>
```

**With Bootstrap CSS:**

```css
.numberCircle {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  position: relative;
}
.numberCircle .height_fix {
  margin-top: 100%;
}
.numberCircle .content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -16px;
  /* Note, this must be half the font size */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="numberCircle">
  <div class="height_fix"></div>
  <div class="content">1</div>
</div>
<div class="numberCircle">
  <div class="height_fix"></div>
  <div class="content">100</div>
</div>
<div class="numberCircle">
  <div class="height_fix"></div>
  <div class="content">10</div>
</div>
```

Screenshot using Bootstrap CSS:

[image]

I tried the same code with Bootstrap CSS and with all divs in a single column & in a single row and it does not work still.

Kindly Help.

Comment: For external css, Please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280636/testing-bootstrap-on-jsfiddle.

Comment: I see your fiddle has `width:160px` and your code has `width:35px` which is working fine with maxcdn?

Comment: Hi with maxcdn its not working fine. the number are coming out of circle.Even circle is smaller than JSFiddle output when maxcdn included

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOYYBb try again this one.

Comment: I checked your code its fine but I want to work with bootstrap maxcdn included because most of my project already dependent on bootstrap now this part is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Css Class **In With Bootstrap CSS**

```
.numberCircle {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  position: relative;
}
```

[Demo JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/u4ccnj83/)

Comment: If this works for you then please click up arrow (This answer is useful). This helps other if anyone needs it.

Comment: I did it says those with less than 15 reputation feedback will be saved.wont shown publicly.

Comment: Got it. I clicked uparrow at first

Answer (score 0):

Okay so problem here is `box-sizing`, as bootstrap or some browser adds `box-sizing:border-box`which have padding and border included in the element's total width and height:, it will not increase size of circle you have used. You will have to add `box-sizing: content-box;` in `.numberCircle`. Read more on `box-sizing` here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing.

You can check updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/89pd04ot/181/

**Edit:** You can check this simple example on [Box Sizing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-sizing)

```css
.numberCircle {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
.numberCircle .height_fix {
  margin-top: 100%;
}
.numberCircle .content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -16px;
  /* Note, this must be half the font size */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="numberCircle">
  <div class="height_fix"></div>
  <div class="content">1</div>
</div>
<div class="numberCircle">
  <div class="height_fix"></div>
  <div class="content">100</div>
</div>
<div class="numberCircle">
  <div class="height_fix"></div>
  <div class="content">10</div>
</div>
```